# Extending the lenght of text to the margin (in a minipage)

Tags: margins, minipage, justification

I wanted to extend the length of the last line in a minipage, so it touches the minipage margin (creates a perfect box of text). I doubt it has any practical use, but im trying to recreate a poem in LaTeX.

[image: imperfect block of text]

Sorry if there is a simple answer, I learned LaTeX basics just today. I hope it's even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `\parfillskip` to `0pt`. If your text is long enough and the width not very narrow, you should be able to achieve your purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}
\kant[1][1-5]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The parameter `\parfillskip` controls the “glue” added at the end of a paragraph, usually it's `0pt plus 1fil` meaning that it has no natural width, but is infinitely stretchable, so the final line of a paragraph is normally flush left.